# guarda imagenes con nombre consecutivo si es el mismo objeto

Tags: python, cv2

Estoy usando un método de detección de objetos y el problema viene al guardar las imágenes con el nombre del objeto detectado: si tengo 3 botellas en una imagen el nombre de las mismas me quede botella_1 , botella_2 , botella_3... pero si encuentra otro objeto como un vaso el no me quede con consecutivo.
en el momento el codigo me sigue un sonsecutivo con todas las etiquetas.

label= nombre del obejto detectado.

```
count = 1

for i in range(len(boxes)):    
    if i in indexes:
        x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
        label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
        color = colors[class_ids[i]]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        recorte = imgAux[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        recorte = cv2.resize(recorte,(150,150), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)  
        cv2.imwrite('recortes/'+ label +'_{}.jpg'.format(count),recorte)
        count = count + 1
        cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y + 30), font, 3, color, 3)

        count += 1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta imagen les explico mejor: tengo 6 botellas detectadas, 1 refrigerador,1 copa... cada recuadro sera el recorte de la imagen que sera guardada, en este momento las imagenes se estan guardando:refrigerador 1,copa 2,botella 3, botella 4 ...etc
lo que necesito es que me quede refrigerador, copa, botella 1 , botella 2, botella 3... etc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo siento no te he entendido, puedes poner una imagen con lo que tienes y otra con el resultado ideal.

Comment: Hola , ya agregue una imagen y una mejor explicacion con ella, de antemano te agradezco.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear un diccionario para manejar el numerador por etiqueta:

```
contador = {}

for i in range(len(boxes)):    
    if i in indexes:
        x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
        label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
        color = colors[class_ids[i]]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        recorte = imgAux[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        recorte = cv2.resize(recorte,(150,150), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

        ##############################################################
        if label not in contador:
           contador[label] = 1
        else:
           contador[label] += 1

        new_label = "{0}_{1}".fromat(label, contador[label])
        ##############################################################
  
        cv2.imwrite('recortes/'+ new_label +'_{}.jpg'.format(count),recorte)
        count = count + 1
        cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y + 30), font, 3, color, 3)
```

Fuera del ciclo, creamos un diccionario `contador`, luego, dentro del ciclo simplemente vamos sumando el contador de cada etiqueta. finalmente definimos un `new_label` que incorpora el número de objeto.